# How to add next and previous button under a carrousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

i want to added a next - prev button to this carousel.th better will be under the carousel and with centred style.
thanks for helping me.

```
<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5" />
  <label for="s1" id="slide1"><script data-video="x8fgrog" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xbf9k.js"></script></label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2"><script data-video="x8fgrog" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xbf9k.js"></script></label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3"><script data-video="x8fgrog" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xbf9k.js"></script></label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4"><script data-video="x8fgrog" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xbf9k.js"></script></label>
  <label for="s5" id="slide5"><script data-video="x8fgrog" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xbf9k.js"></script></label>
</section>

<style>
[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  height: 55vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(-30%,0,-200px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
#s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(-15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(30%,0,-200px);
}

#slide1 { background: #00BCD4 }
#slide2 { background: #4CAF50 }
#slide3 { background: #CDDC39 }
#slide4 { background: #FFC107 }
#slide5 { background: #FF5722 }
</style>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking for (and repeating the same question 5 times will not get you a better answer).  If you are just asking for CSS to position two buttons below your `<section>`, you can see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/safq1rh5/17/) for a simple example (but there are many, many ways to accomplish the same effect).  But since you have already provided quite a bit of fairly complex CSS, I assume this is not actually the question?

Comment: i'm sorry but for  the code "this fiddle" not work that mean when i click it never change and swipe the slide the carousel

Comment: Yes, I didn't create a fully-functional implementation, and this is why I asked you to clarify your question, because it's not clear what you are actually asking.  I think that StackOverflow is best used for asking and answering discrete, targeted questions, but it seems like your question is "can you implement this carousel for me?".  I could, but this will take me some time, and since it's not clear that you have made an attempt at solving it yourself, I think that this is a little outside the intended purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: There will be plenty of tutorials and blogposts online about how to create this type of UI though, such as [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp), and I would encourage you to check some of those out to get yourself started.  Or perhaps another StackOverflow user with a bit more free time than me will be gracious enough to do some implementation for you.